# How to force rebase before each delivery?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We set policy to force rebase before delivery if any baseline is recommended.

But we would not recommend baseline everyday. We will do it once in 2 weeks like that.

In between recommend baseline duration, people are often facing issues in functionality as they have not taken latest code base.

Is there any way to force to rebase before each delivery? [irrespective of baseline is recommended or not].

Is it recommended practice to rebase before each delivery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to rebase before delivering, and it usually is based on the "recommended baseline" mechanism.

So even if you said "irrespective of baseline is recommended or not", I would still suggest you look at "[this deliver policy: 'Rebase before delivery'](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pol_rbs_befdlvr.htm)".

> This policy (**`Require development stream to be based on the project's recommended baseline(s) prior to delivery`**) requires developers to rebase their source streams to the target stream current recommended baselines before they deliver work to the target stream.
>   The policy can be set per project or per stream, for interproject and intraproject deliver operations.
>
> The goal of this policy is to have developers build and test their work in their development work areas against the work included in the most recent stable baselines before they deliver to the target stream. This practice minimizes the amount of merging that developers must do when they perform deliver operations.

From [UCM policies](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_ucmproj_policies.htm):

[image: deliver policies]

---

If you don't recommend baselines on the parent stream, then you need to define a preop deliver trigger (as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14116547)):

```
cleartool mktrtype -ucm -preop deliver_start -execwin ccperl "\\share\path\to\script.pl" -c "Check if rebase activity exists before delivering" rebase_before_delivery@\pvob
```

With `script.pl` a script which would list all activities of the current stream, checking if the latest activity is a `rebase.xxx` one.

```
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14116547
```

Comment: So only way to force rebase before delivery is to recommend baseline and set the policy.Isn't it? How frequent we can recommend baseline? we should recommend only stable deliverable, isn't it?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: the "recommend baseline" is the native mechanism allowing you to force developers to rebase before delivering. You can recommend as often as you like, but you shouldn't create and recommend baselines every 5 minutes. If they are recommended, they should pass a certain level of quality (at least compile).