# How to list all modified files in actual view?

Tags: clearcase

Is there a way to list all files modified since last deliver with clearcase ?

I'm using clearcase like this :

```
ct setview <myStreamName>
```

Then I work on files. But before deliver to integration stream, I want to check all modified file. Is there a way to list all file with pending changes and compare them with working revision ?

**Edit :**

`<myStreamName>` is a child stream with activities, created from integration stream.

Comment: I have [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58344882/6309) to include the explanation for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

[`setview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) will mask your current view, since you access your files directly through /vobs/yourVobs/.../yourfiles ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579977/6309)).

If you are doing a deliver, that means you are using **[UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976424/6309)** and have set a baseline from your current view, on your current stream  (that you are about to deliver to an integration stream).

If that is the case, do a [diff between two baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559296/6309): (`cleartool diffbl -ver baseline1@\apvob baseline2@\apvob`)

- the latest one of the integration stream.
- the one you have set

For the first element, use a [`ct lsbl -comp C -stream S`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132683/6309) to get the latest baseline.

This assumes you are delivering *one* component.

I also mention [`deliver -preview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm) in "[ClearCase Inter project delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10305318/6309)": it needs an UCM view on the *target UCM stream* to operate.
See also "[I need a list of all the component of a certain stream that still needs delivery to default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591909/6309)".

---

The error message:

```
Error: Target stream "myStream" requires child development streams 
       to rebase to recommended baselines before performing deliver operation.
```

means the deliver policy "[Require development stream to be based on the project's recommended baseline(s) prior to delivery)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pol_rbs_befdlvr.htm)" is in place.
See "[How to force rebase before each delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892060/6309)"

Try and change that policy, or, as enforced, rebase first.
Then do a `deliver -preview`.

Comment: Since we're talking UCM here, deliver lets you see what would go across in a default deliver -- all undelivered changes, by activity & version. You're actually showing part of the logic deliver -preview uses...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that isn't quite right. The simplest way to see your pending changes is to run `cleartool deliver -preview -long` while set in your development view.

This will list all the undelivered activities and the versions on those activities, regardless of the component.

You can use diffbl, more or less, but you then have to delve into the mysteries of deliverbl baselines (created on every deliver operation listing the activities delivered in that deliver.) and use those baselines as a filter on the activities... This then gets more complicated because you can deliver the same activity multiple times if you delivered it, did more work on it, and then haven't delivered the additional work.

Just use deliver -preview -long...

Comment: I have try this but I have an error message `Error: Target stream "myStream" requires child development streams to rebase to recommanded baselines before performing deliver operation.` I don't know why, I created "myStream" as child from integration stream.